# How can i open and run a project in laravel that isn't mine?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have to comment and optimize a Laravel project that is made by the previous back end developer that was at the firm I'm working at. The problem is that I am a junior developer and I don't really know where to check for it. I downgraded my PHP version because it required PHP 7.2.5 or 7.3. I changed the .env database name, host, etc and migrated all the migrations, but it still doesn't work. What should I check next, and where? Its a big project for a consulting web site.

It can't connect to the database I think, like I get a white page, no frontend loaded at all.I will paste here the env and a ss to the database:

```
APP_NAME=your-consult
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:93DE6wrEWKiM8q2EtC6TanandzVydkkFPNeSRqYBbeE=
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_URL=http://localhost:8000
APP_API_URL=http://localhost:8000


LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=admin_yourconsultdb
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=your-consult.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=no-reply@your-consult.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=TestareYouCo1@
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=no-reply@your-consult.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=Your-Consult.Com

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"

MIX_URL=http://localhost:8000
MIX_API_URL=http://localhost:8000/api
MIX_API_STORAGE=http://localhost:8000/storage
MIX_ASSETS=assets

MIX_STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY=pk_live_51HKjElD55LzIx6Do5Cf5tRoklBwZ6DCpo3iA15zN7tDJFTAnOqjAfpgcRwn5apeaYO7Z6iidg3U8QaN6UjW3PLfI001nPJzryy
MIX_STRIPE_SECRET_KEY=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
SUCCESS_URL=https://your-consult.com/comanda-finalizata
CANCEL_URL=https://your-consult.com/comanda-nefinalizata
EURO_VAL=5
PAYMENT_REFERENCE=false

JWT_SECRET=BrDqF6W8G5zkchvFOVIHXmtkRu0n30B1YnwyJWFuObzf8UPRdq7WpDPFozqgHo8i

COMPANY_VAT_CODE=39382763

SERIES_NAME=YC
SERIES_NAME_PROF=PROF
CURRENCY=RON
LANGUAGE=RO

DOCUSIGN_USERNAME=sales@your-consult.com
DOCUSIGN_AUTH_PATH=account.docusign.com
DOCUSIGN_URL=https://eu.docusign.net/restapi
DOCUSIGN_INTEGRATOR_KEY=c2c2099a-0565-407d-826e-dc80a94eae0c
DOCUSIGN_API_ACCOUNT_ID=8c4086f6-d3ab-4d9b-b92d-669a9c2e7433
DOCUSIGN_API_USERNAME=79e0084e-5e71-4de1-b900-4fd8ad7afb7e


TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN=9a93920b0615907945b31249266c4b1b
TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID=AC71d96e6a926df0c039acabcfdaad9b23
TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER=+14439988274

NETOPIA_MOBILPAY_PAYMENT_URL=https://secure.mobilpay.ro
NETOPIA_MOBILPAY_PUBLIC_CERT=live.68FY-TQUB-RU29-67WK-HBGD.public.cer
NETOPIA_MOBILPAY_PRIVATE_KEY=live.68FY-TQUB-RU29-67WK-HBGDprivate.key

BITPAY_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH=bitpay.pri
BITPAY_PUBLIC_KEY_PATH=bitpay.pub
BITPAY_NETWORK=livenet
BITPAY_KEY_STORAGE_PASSWORD=Lamunca123
BITPAY_TOKEN=5WgNp6eNogQXyMYBs5GdSBZ5ePcP7thViD4ZGLZ285Ah

CREATIVE_SMS_TOKEN=I2kPdRTL3pvtH9oX1A25E9vztKvR1U3D4Atx9nmyjVJcceH7fbEjilM1rIhf
```

[image: the database image]

Comment: If it's a big project, are there no other developers in the company who can advise on the project? No documentation left behind? Anyway, we can't help you much as it stands because you've provided no real details about the project or where exactly you're stuck - "doesn't work" tells us precisely nothing about the nature of your problem. Please read [ask] and then update your post to provide clarity and specfics about your issue. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson its a small firm in their first year so everyone is overloaded with work i will update the question immedeatly

Comment: `i get a white page`... see [How can I get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-can-i-get-useful-error-messages-in-php) for how you can try to improve on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can check seeder (database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php) and run with command "php artisan db:seed"
and i think some config missing you run command "composer dump-autoload" to regenerate that. Hope that is solution for your problem.

Comment: i tried that but it still isnt working